# YouTube Android Player API not supported

Tags: android, youtube

I try to download YouTube Android Player API but I found This SDK is no longer supported or maintained by YouTube. It will be fully deprecated on or after May 1, 2023. This SDK should not be used, due to security vulnerabilities. Please use the YouTube IFrame Player API instead.

so I cannot load videos from youtube in my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they say in the banner, you should use the IFramePlayer API inside a Webview.

Otherwise you can use this library (I am the owner): [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player). It uses the IFrame Player API inside a Webview but offers a native interface to it, so you can use Java/Kotlin to interact with the player.

Comment: your library was my first choice but there is Popup appearing while scrolling like this issue

https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/issues/848

Comment: I have update issue #848 with a solution, hope this helps :)

Comment: @PierfrancescoSoffritti We have devices in production already using the deprecated Android Youtube player API. We just noticed this message a few days ago and started working on changing it to the IFramePlayer API. However, we are unsure if we will be ready by May 1, 2023. Does this deprecation mean it will stop working for existing apps? If yes, will it be on May 1, 2023, or sometime later?

Comment: Hi, I don't know what will happen to the official YouTube Player from Google.